# How to use \num for all numbers in text? (siunitx)

Tags: tables, siunitx

I want to use `\num` (from the package [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)) for all the numbers in my document, tables included. (I have a lot and it would take a lot of time to do it manually.)

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid this is not possible.

Comment: Maybe using regular expressions?

Comment: The `S` column type is pretty close to applying `\num`.

Comment: How are the numbers in your document formatted at present?

Comment: i'm using `\usepackage[group-separator={\ }]{siunitx}`

Answer (score 4):

Applying a macro to all numbers in a document globally is so far I know not possible.

What you can do is using an advanced feature of many text editors called [*regular expressions*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) to search and replace all numbers in your document files to add the `\num` this way.

Just get an text editor which has this feature, like the free [Notpad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), and try the following text as regular expression:

```
([+-]? *\d+(?:\.\d*)?)
```

and as replacement text:

```
\\num{\1}
```

[image: Screenshot]

This regular expression searches for all numbers with or without + or -, maybe followed by spaces, and with or without a fractional part. It then adds the found number into `\num{..}`.

> Make sure that you make a backup of your files first!